# Usuários inexperientes marcando ✓ em mais de 1 resposta

Tags: debate, resposta-aceita

Um dos *dramas* que tenho enfrentado ao longo da minha experiência no SOpt é em relação à marcação (aceitação) de resposta por parte de usuário novos — outros nem tanto novos, mas ainda inexperientes com as ferramentas e funcionamento do site.

**O que acontece?**

O usuário (AP) faz uma pergunta e recebe, digamos, 2 respostas, sendo que fui o primeiro a responder. Como por padrão as respostas aparecem em ordem decrescente de antiguidade e o AP achou a minha resposta melhor do que a outra, ele acha que deve clicar no ícone **✓** de todas as respostas para marcá-las como *úteis*. Como a minha resposta foi a primeira da lista, acaba que a última resposta (a outra que não a minha) acaba por, erroneamente, ficar como a *resposta escolhida*.

Noto isso porque vejo aparecendo no ícone de "Conquistas recentes" o `+15` e ao acessar a pergunta, me deparo com a outra resposta marcada como aceita e os `15pts`, antes adicionados, debitados da minha reputação.

Ao suspeitar que o usuário cometeu o erro descrito mais acima, eu deixo a ele um comentário na pergunta informando a possibilidade de tal equívoco e ao mesmo tempo instruindo-o de que ele deve marcar **✓** em apenas 1 resposta.

Estimo que em 90% dos casos ele volta a marcar a minha resposta (muitas vezes acompanhado de um pedido de desculpas por inexperiência), ou seja, foi um engano como descrito aqui. Claro que em alguns casos não foi engano, foi mudança de escolha mesmo. O AP de repente decidiu marcar outra resposta. Isso é tranquilo e eu acho que ele tem todo direito e liberdade pra isso. Até porque eu não estimulo o AP a escolher a minha resposta, mas apenas indagando-o sobre a possibilidade do erro de achar que deve marcar todas as respostas com **✓**.

> Se eu não me atentasse a isso e não corresse atrás, teria
>   deixado muitas respostas minhas sem serem marcadas com **✓**.

Isso tem sido bem estressante, pois acaba sendo uma coisa repetitiva e corriqueira. Além do que isso é ruim para a comunidade, porque acaba que a resposta marcada fora feita de forma errada, sem a intenção do AP.

Em vista disso, não seria algo importante se o SOpt (tanto o pt quando os outros da rede) tivesse algum tipo de confirmação alertando o AP de que ele já havia marcado uma resposta e que marcando outra irá desmarcar a anterior? Talvez isso impedisse que essas coisas acontecessem. Existe alguma maneira de propor isso aos desenvolvedores do site?

Comment: Acho que pelo menos no tooltipe do ícone de aceitação ✓ poderia haver junto como o texto que já aparece algo tipo *"só é permitido marcar uma resposta como aceita"* Isso as vezes poderia fazer o AP refletir melhor sobre qual marcar

Comment: Considere-se com sorte... Isso quando eles marcam alguma resposta como correta. Vejo muitos abandonando suas perguntas, não dando nem upvote. Em [alguns casos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/298128/um-jquery-get-dentro-de-outro-jquery-get/298141#comment605939_298141) eles até agradecem, mas não usam a ferramenta do site. As vezes penso que a ferramenta de tooltip está ficando defasada. O usuário gosta de clicar num botão sem ler coisa nenhuma, até o tooltip aparecer ele já mudou de página 3 vezes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [resposta do @Renan](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7088/8063) foi muito boa, mas discordo na sua entrada, onde diz *"Eu acho isso o menor dos problemas."*.

Não acho que seja o "menor dos problemas". Talvez não seja um problema muito importante, mas dizer taxativamente "o menor" acho exagerado.

O fato de usuários que ainda não entenderam as funções do site acharem que marcando ✔️ em tudo está fazendo certo é um problema que tem uma certa relevância, conforme expliquei na pergunta.

Isso desvirtua o propósito mais básico do site: a pergunta casada com a resposta correta (mesmo que não seja a melhor) e eleita pelo usuário que perguntou.

Mas concordo com a ideia de que teria que ter um tempo de espera para marcar ✔️ em outra resposta. Isso poderia de forma eficaz evitar o equívoco que levantei na pergunta.

Comment: Eu me pergunto... Se a pergutna for transformada em publicação wiki, é possível para a comunidade alterar a resposta correta? Assim daria para corrigir o equívoco, caso o usuário mude a resposta correta várias vezes.

Answer (score 9):

Eu acho isso o menor dos problemas.

De qualquer forma, para resolver, acho que o melhor seria um tempo de espera. Por exemplo: após se marcar uma resposta como escolhida, deve-se esperar pelo menos cinco minutos para mudar essa marcação. A indicação textual disso seria semelhante à indicação que nós temos para a impossibilidade de se mudar o voto em publicação inédita após certo tempo.

Isso demonstraria aos novatos que a resposta escolhida é única, e que a decisão é séria, de uma forma intuitiva e suave. Já para os usuários experientes, a mudança seria praticamente imperceptível.

Para sugerir isso aos desenvolvedores, acho que o melhor lugar é o metão.

Comment: É, seria interessante tb.